# How to set reference Object's value before insert?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dml, relationships

Object a has many of object b, How can I determine an object reference before insert ?
When I determine object b information for example number, name, .. and I want to insert it to an object of objects a . How to set the specific object a before insert ?

```
public line_item__c lineItem {get; set;} 
public Invoice__c invoice {get; set;} 
public pageReference additem(){ 
  lineItem.Invoices__r = invoice; 
  insert(lineItem); 
}
```

Comment: Can clarify this a little? By "object" do you mean sObject? And do you want to do this in Apex, or in some integration with salesforce? It might also help if you used the names of real objects: "Object order__c has many of object line_item__c".

Comment: exactly like Invoice__c and line_item__c, I choice Invoice which number is 100, and add an item to it, now when I write insert(lineItem); I got error with null pointer exception because the reference invoice not determined (null).

Comment: What is the code you are using to "add an item to it"? Seeing that would be very helpful to try to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: public line_item__c lineItem {get; set;}
public Invoice__c invoice {get; set;}

public pageReference additem(){
lineItem.Invoices__r = invoice;
        insert(lineItem);
}

Comment: I've taken the liberty of pasting your code into your question and formatting it. in the future, I would suggest you use this instead of putting code in comments...that can be hard to read. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think where your code is letting you down, is you've not ensured you've saved the invoice before you add the reference to the line_item__c object.

In order to have one related to the other, you would need to add a relationship field to line_item__c. This produces the sometimes unexpected result of there being two fields present that refer to the order. The typical names/datatypes of these fields in line_item__c would be as follows

```
field name          data type
-------------       ----------------
invoice__c            id (primitive data type stored in DB)
invoice__r            invoice__c (sObject data type, only stored in memory as reference to parent record)
```

Some code that would serve to create an order and a line item might look like this:

```
invoice__c invoice = new invoice__c();
invoice.status__c = 'New';
... 
insert invoice
//this immediately populates the id value of invoice

if (invoice.id != null) {
  line_item__c li = new line_item__c();
  li.invoice__c = invoice.id; 
  ...
  insert li;
}
```

this is the equivalent of what you are doing:

```
invoice__c invoice = new invoice__c();
invoice.status__c = 'New';
... 
insert invoice
//this immediately populates the id value of invoice

if (invoice.id != null) {
  line_item__c li = new line_item__c();
  li.invoice__r = invoice; 
  ...
  insert li;
}
```

Both of these will work, but the insert of the line_item__c will only succeed if there is actually an `invoice__c.id` value to make the association between invoice and line item. But this is not always true with relationships in the platform. I suspect that your relationship is either a Master-Detail or a required Lookup relationship.

Comment: Ok, I tried the second block and its work fine ! but the problem is I want to determine the li.invoice__r of an existing li not create new object, because I entered some fields of list item at my UI. the lineItem saved with only the invoice field and other fields empty

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you are trying to add a new invoice to the line item or assign an existing one. If you are trying to add a new invoice to the line item, first you have to create an instance of an sObject of type **Invoice__c** - just declaring it as a member field does not create an instance of it.

Try this:

```
public line_item__c lineItem {get; set;} 
public Invoice__c invoice {get; set;} 

public pageReference additem(){ 
    invoice = new Invoice__c();
    lineItem.Invoices__r = invoice; 
    insert(lineItem); 
}
```

...or even better:

```
public line_item__c lineItem {get; set;} 

public pageReference additem(){ 
    Invoice__c invoice = new Invoice__c();
    lineItem.Invoices__r = invoice; 
    insert(lineItem); 
}
```

But have in mind that you should also perform insert/update/upsert operation on your lineItem record to store the changes made to it.

Comment: No, before I add items to invoice I get an Invoice with Select, then I add items to that invoice with number 100 for example.